# How to Install non-Adafruit libraries on a circuitpython board?

Tags: python, libraries, adafruit-circuitpython

Total Newbie here!
At first: I made a python script for a simple PID controller with a SPI sensor board and I2C Display. It runs on a Raspberry Pi and controls a small furnace. Since the raspberry (in my case) is pretty prone to freeze or do unexpected things, I want to move all this to a microcontroller.
Things I already did:

- I bought a seeduino xiao a while ago and installed circuitpython on
  it as stated here:
  https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Seeeduino-XIAO-CircuitPython/
- I tried a simple script for blinking the onboard LED
- I installed the Adafruit library for my sensor by putting the *.mpy into the /lib folder

What needs to follow next:

- Install the PID-controller library (https://pypi.org/project/simple-pid/) and the I2C display library (https://github.com/winneymj/CircuitPython_SH1106)

My problem is finding a way to download these libraries and make them useable for my script. I assume that I somehow need to make .mpy files first and then copy them into the /lib folder, too. How can I do this? Or do I even have to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get a PID controller working in CircuitPython?